# Cannot connect to VM via browser, but can via curl?

Tags: curl

I have a VM running that I can connect to from the host via ping, telnet, and curl (port 80), but cannot connect via the browser (any browser).

What's going on, and how can I get around this?

(The VM has a host-only network connection on 192.168.100.100).

**[UPDATE 1: more details]**

The VM is a VirtualBox VM, Ubuntu 12.04, running Nginx. Django is running in the background (using Gunicorn), forwarded from Nginx on port 5000, but that isn't the issue here - the issue is a complete lack of response from port 80 - just the default browser (browser-specific) 'This webpage is not available' page.

The curl command is:

```
curl 192.168.100.100 -i
```

and the response is:

```
$ curl 192.168.100.100 -i
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 11:49:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://192.168.100.100/

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

this is what I expect (as there is some SSL re-direction required). If I `curl https://192.168.100.100 -k` I get the HTML for the actual endpoint post-redirect, so I know that's working.

**[UPDATE 2: more info]**

The problem is intermittent. I did a full `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` roundtrip to reboot from scratch, and suddenly it worked. Then ten minutes later it stopped working - so I then tried renewing DHCP lease to 're-acquire' my network settings, and that made it work again. So it looks like some interference at the network level.

Anyway - I have a solution now (renew DHCP), but would love any diagnostic help for future reference.

Comment: Can you give more information about the curl response and how could you understand that you can not connect via browser, what response does the browser give you?

Comment: Added more details into the question.

Comment: in my case, global mode proxy was turned on...